# vkAPI. Как получить counters

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

всем привет. пишу бота на python который по id  страницы вк выдавал информацию. так вот.
Получаю по апи такой ответ
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Там есть counters. так вот.

```
url = f"https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids={id}&fields=verified,status,screen_name,counters,friend_status,online,blacklisted&access_token={atoken}&v=5.131"
response = requests.get(url, verify=True)
r = response.json()
print('{r["response"]["counters"][0]["audios"]}')
```

При данном коде вылазит ошибка KeyError: 0 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При обращении к элементу `r["response"]["counters"]` вы получите словарь, ибо значение ключа `"counters"` в словаре `r["response"]` - это словарь.
Далее вы пытаетесь получить значение по ключу `0`, а данный ключ отсутствует в словаре, о чем интерпретатор и выдает вам ошибку.

Корректный код:

```py
url = f"https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids={id}&fields=verified,status,screen_name,counters,friend_status,online,blacklisted&access_token={atoken}&v=5.131"
response = requests.get(url, verify=True)
r = response.json()
print(r["response"][0]["counters"]["audios"])
```

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Верно, я не заметил, что r["response"] возвращает список. Нам нужен первый его элемент. Изменил код соответственно.